# Pass Link Associated with Image Onmouseover

Tags: javascript

I need to pass the link associated with 5 different images dynamically to a different image. I have already created the function that changes the image, but this is the last part that I haven't been able to find an answer to. Here is my code so far:

```
<html>
<head><title>Revolving Pictures</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">          
        function changeBigPic(newPic){
            var big = document.getElementById("bigPic");
            big.src = newPic;
    //***How do I get the href of the 'album' images to 'bigPic'? I'm also trying to double the size of bigPic and using 200% makes the image enormous! Thanks in advance   
}
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <img name="bigPic" id="bigPic" src="album1.jpg" height="200%" width="200%"><br />

<A HREF="http://stevenseagal.com/"><img src="album1.jpg" id="segal" onmouseover="changeBigPic(document.getElementById('segal').src);">

&nbsp <A HREF="http://www.richardcheese.com/" target="_blank"><img src="album2.jpg" id="cheese" onmouseover="changeBigPic(document.getElementById('cheese').src);">

&nbsp <A HREF="http://www.myspace.com/etjusticepourtous" target="_blank"><img src="album3.jpg" id="justice" onmouseover="changeBigPic(document.getElementById('justice').src);">

&nbsp <A HREF="http://www.bestcoast.us/" target="_blank"><img src="album4.jpg" id="bestCoast" onmouseover="changeBigPic(document.getElementById('bestCoast').src);">

&nbsp <A HREF="http://www.van-halen.com/" target="_blank"><img src="album5.jpg"       id="vanHalen" onmouseover="changeBigPic(document.getElementById(this.id).src);">

 </body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the easiest way is to pass the img object instead of only its source.

Replace onmouseovers with `onmouseover="changeBigPic(this);"` and the new changeBigPic function would be something like:

```
function changeBigPic(element){
    var big = document.getElementById("bigPic");
    big.src = element.src;

    // To get the href of the parent node:
    var href = element.parentNode.href;
}
```

Comment: Okay, the first part works now. I then added the line:     big.parentnode.href = href; and <A HREF="" target="_blank"> ahead of "bigPic" but firebug says that "big.parentnode is undefined" from within the function. Also, big.style.height *= 2; & big.style.width *= 2; is not working either to change the size. Thanks in advance

Comment: DOM properties such as `parentNode` are case-sensitive. `big.parentNode.href = href;` works fine.
I didn't notice it but there are many errors in your HTML document: the final tag must be prepended by a forward slash (`</html>`) and `img` and `a` tags must also be closed. You can get more details about it on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_elements.asp). 
About changing the size, if you know the size of the first image, just put the raw value instead of "200%" and you can use `big.style.width = 2*element.width; big.style.height = 2*element.height;` in changeBigPic function.